# Python: How to append data created in nested loop after every incremental iteration

Tags: python, loops, nested

Example: if each iteration returns 10 observations and there are 4 iterations, final table should have 40 observations.
This is the query I wrote:

```
Df_All = pd.DataFrame() 

for i in Vars:
    for j in Type:
        i_j = df[df['Product'] == j].groupby([i,'Var1', 'Var2']).count()[['Var3']].reset_index()

    i_j['Var'] = i

Df_All = Df_All.append(i_j)
```

Comment: Move the last line to within the two for loops

Comment: Thanks for responding.. That does help in appending, but output is not correct. the last iteration over rules earlier ones and append outputs only the last group by and all other rows are almost filled with NaN

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you further since it is unclear what the output you expect looks like, and I can't reproduce your result (your code isn't runnable). Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)